# Check if function/extension is defined

Tags: symfony, twig, knpmenubundle

In my Symfony2 bundle, I need to check if a function (an extension) is defined. More specifically, if the KnpMenuBundle is installed I use that one in my bundle, otherwise I will render the plugin myself.

I tried this, but this of course doesn't work:

```
{% if knp_menu_render() is defined %}
    {# do something #}
{% else %}
    {# do something else #}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a test/function/filter to check if a function is defined? If not, is there another way to check if the KnpMenuBundle is installed in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function in a [Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) which would check if bundle is enabled.

List of registered bundles is stored in the `kernel.bundles` parameter.

Twig extensions are registered as services. This means you can pass any other service or a parameter to your extension:

```
<services>
    <service id="acme.twig.acme_extension" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension">

        <argument>%kernel.bundles%</argument>

        <tag name="twig.extension" />
    </service>
</services>
```

In your Twig function or filter you can later use a service or a parameter which you've passed to an extension.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of that, but I thought is was not a good practise to create an extension for this in a bundle which isn't related to the function of the extension? (for instance, a `TwigBundle` is more related)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need, so I created my own extension:

```
class IsLoadedExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    protected $environment;

    public function initRuntime(\Twig_Environment $environment)
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of functions to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array An array of functions
     */
    public function getTests()
    {
        return array(
                new \Twig_SimpleTest('loaded', [$this, 'hasExtension']),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return boolean
     */
    function hasExtension($name)
    {
        return $this->environment->hasExtension($name);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'amce_extension_exists';
    }
}
```

Then registered it in Twig:

```
services:
    acme_somebundle.twig.is_loaded_extension:
        class: Acme\SomeBundle\Twig\IsLoadedExtension
        tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

And used it in twig template like this:

```
{% if 'knp_menu' is loaded %}
  {# use knp menu #}
{% endif %}
```